# Python or Pandas left outer join or merge with one key as a list

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to do a `left outer join` on two Data.Frames using Python. The goal is to get a column from right into left based on if the key from left exists in the list from right.

My initial thought was to use Pandas, so I wrote something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({'name':['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'], 'leftkey':[11, 22, 33]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'var':['foo', 'bar'], 'rightkey':[[1, 2, 5], [2, 33, 100]]})

merged = pandas.merge(left, right, left_on='keyleft', right_on='keyright', how='left')
```

As we can see, `left_on` is a single variable, while `right_on` is a `list`.

I would expect `merged` to look something like this:

```
|   | name | leftkey | var | rightkey   |
|---|------|---------|-----|------------|
| 0 | spam | 11      | NaN | NaN        |
| 1 | ham  | 22      | NaN | NaN        |
| 2 | eggs | 33      | bar | [2,33,100] |
```

However, all of `var` and `rightkey` end up being `NaN`.

I realize that I could just put everything in R and have this done. Perhaps I'm overthinking things and this does not even require Pandas. However, my hope is to keep the pipeline in Python for as long as possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to build a new column that you can use as the `right_on` argument in `merge`:

```
right = right.assign(rightkey_x = right['rightkey']).explode('rightkey_x')
```

Output:

```
   var      rightkey rightkey_x
0  foo     [1, 2, 5]          1
0  foo     [1, 2, 5]          2
0  foo     [1, 2, 5]          5
1  bar  [2, 33, 100]          2
1  bar  [2, 33, 100]         33
1  bar  [2, 33, 100]        100
```

Then you can merge both dataframes and drop the helper column:

```
pd.merge(left, right, left_on='leftkey', right_on='rightkey_x', how='left')\
.drop('rightkey_x', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   name leftkey  var      rightkey
0  spam      11  NaN           NaN
1   ham      22  NaN           NaN
2  eggs      33  bar  [2, 33, 100]
```

Comment: This solution may end up being the option I go with, but not accepting it just yet. My concerns are 1) that this will create a decent amount of slow-down when applied to 100k+ entries, and 2) that there is a more aesthetically pleasing solution.

That being said, thank you! I will give this a go shortly and see if it at least gets me to the next bend in the pipeline.

Comment: Of course. Unfortunately, Pandas doesn't always has an aesthetically pleasing solution like R. In any case first you need to extract those values from lists.